# What do you call the large golden arrow in the middle of a wheel of fortune?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there a particular word for this? I can't think of anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special.  Perhaps the "pointer" or "the arrow".

We would probably not refer directly to the arrow, but use an expression like "He span the wheel of fortune and it landed on $400"

Comment: +1 I think there's nothing wrong with this.